# Can an Android device be locked down by an administrator?

Tags: security, device-administrator

I would like to know if it is possible to use android devices in a work environment with restrictions on the phones usage.

These phones would be given to members in the field to log data, and only that. Is there a simple solution that exists for this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Yes indeed.  Android 2.2 and higher supports [Microsoft Exchange security policies](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2-highlights.html) as well as [administrator applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).